# Particular patterns for zeros of high-degree named polynomials

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, roots

A polynomial may have its roots at any location in the complex plane. However various famous polynomials have their roots on certain curves. My question is why, and I am looking for references in this regard. How to parametrize such roots and what is the limit curve, etc.

The most famous is of course the unit circle on which the roots of $z^n=1$ live. But other named polynomials show interesting patterns as well. For example the roots of [Bernoulli polynomials](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RootsOfTheBernoulliPolynomials/) show up in a double horseshoe pattern. Is the resulting curve discussed in any reference? Any lead for roots of high-degree well-known polynomial is of interest.

Edit:

One connection is [Szego curve](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SzegoeCurve/). In relation to $1+x+x^2/2!+...+x^n/n!=0$. See [a paper in Transactions of AMS](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2155576).

Another is [truncated version of cosine function.](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Etdupuy/notes/partialsums.pdf)